# Angular2 *ngFor in select list, set active based on string from object

Tags: angular, typescript, select, ngfor

I'm trying using the `ngFor` on my select DropDownList. Have loaded in the options which should be in the dropdown.

The code you see here:

```
<div class="column small-12 large-2">
    <label class="sbw_light">Title:</label><br />
    <select [(ngModel)]="passenger.Title">
       <option *ngFor="#title of titleArray" [value]="title.Value">{{title.Text}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Based on this code, it produces a dropdown which look like this image.

[image]

The problem is that I want to set one of them "Mr or Mrs" as the active one based on the `passenger.Title` which is a string either "Mr" or "Mrs".

Any can help see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 95):

This should work

```ts
<option *ngFor="let title of titleArray" 
    [value]="title.Value" 
    [attr.selected]="passenger.Title==title.Text ? true : null">
  {{title.Text}}
</option>
```

I'm not sure the `attr.` part is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer!

Comment: Adding the "? true : null" to the [select] attribute is what worked for me. I searched on this for a couple of days. In my case, I'm pulling Asp.Net TimeZone Ids from an API and allowing the user to select the correct one.

Comment: doing it this way, i get, title does not exist on component.ts

Answer (score 19):

Check it out in [**this demo fiddle**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ems5ek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), go ahead and change the dropdown or default values in the code.

Setting the `passenger.Title` with a value that equals to a `title.Value` should work.

View:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="passenger.Title">
    <option *ngFor="let title of titleArray" [value]="title.Value">
      {{title.Text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

TypeScript used:

```
class Passenger {
  constructor(public Title: string) { };
}
class ValueAndText {
  constructor(public Value: string, public Text: string) { }
}

...
export class AppComponent {
    passenger: Passenger = new Passenger("Lord");

    titleArray: ValueAndText[] = [new ValueAndText("Mister", "Mister-Text"),
                                  new ValueAndText("Lord", "Lord-Text")];

}
```