# How can I make a map in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to achieve a `.map` of react with angular.

Example at React:

```
const options = ['Car', 'Bus', 'Truck', 'Bike', 'Motorcycle'];
const compTest = () => (
  <select>
    {options.map((vehicle) => <option>{vehicle}</option>)}
  </select>
)
```

How I do this with an angular component?

Comment: You need to use `*ngFor` to display [list](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2). [A related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35513049/2873538).

Comment: `<select>
<option *ngFor="let item of options">{{item}}</option>
</select>` (https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)

Comment: **1.** AngularJS != Angular2+. **2.** If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through their quick tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some of the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component.ts file

```
options = ['Car', 'Bus', 'Truck', 'Bike', 'Motorcycle'];
```

in your component.html file

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

and here is StackBlitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nrzght

Comment: Sure! Thank you, sanka!